# How does ruby represent strings internally?

Tags: c, ruby, encoding, character-encoding, ruby-c-extension

I ran into some trouble while creating a C-Extension for ruby that got me thinking. I wonder how Ruby (1.9.1) handles strings (and all the encoding-stuff) internally?

If I have a string like `"o"`, and I pass the string to a C-Function (as `VALUE`), I can deal with it pretty easily using the `RSTRING_PTR()` and the `RSTRING_LEN()` macro. However, if I make the string `ö` (a german umlaut character), `RSTRING_LEN()` will give me `2`.

I'm a bit stumped on the contents of `RSTRING_PTR()` in that case, the two bytes are `0xA4` and `0xC3`. What encoding is this? I tried using `"ö".force_encoding( ... )` with different encodings before passing the string to the C-function, but that does not affect the contents of `RSTRING_PTR` at all.

What I need is a way to have the string represented as a `WCHAR*` encoded in `UTF-16` (in the case of `"ö"`, that would be `0x00F6`) in my C-function, but that's kinda hard to do if you do not know what encoding you're coming from...

thx for any help in advance

Comment: `force_encoding` isn't supposed to change the contents of the string, it just changes how the string is read.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

String internals in ruby 1.9 depends on `__ENCODING__` constant and `Encoding.default_internal` setting.

In your case it looks like UTF-8 (default), but `ö` is actually `c3 b6` in UTF-8, and `c3 a4` is `ä`

Comment: oh yeah, you're right I mixed up my testcases. Thx for the help, conversion works now =)